# Pandas - Generate date column from other TimeStamp columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've a DataFrame as below -

| date | time | url | username | ip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-22 | 1900-01-01 00:00:02 | /test/fun.aspx | mitesh | 192.168.0.25 |
| 2022-02-23 | 1900-01-01 01:00:02 | /test/run.aspx | steve | 192.168.0.15 |
| 2022-02-24 | 1900-01-01 01:00:02 | /test/bun.aspx | azim | 192.168.0.11 |

I need a new datetime column constructed by taking year, month and day from the  *date* column and hour, minute, second from the *time* column.

New to pandas.  Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways, the most efficient is probably to concatenate the date and time to feed to [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']+' '
                               +df['time'].str.extract('(\S+)$',
                                                       expand=False)
                                )
```

output:

```
         date                 time             url username            ip            datetime
0  2022-02-22  1900-01-01 00:00:02  /test/fun.aspx   mitesh  192.168.0.25 2022-02-22 00:00:02
1  2022-02-23  1900-01-01 01:00:02  /test/run.aspx    steve  192.168.0.15 2022-02-23 01:00:02
2  2022-02-24  1900-01-01 01:00:02  /test/bun.aspx     azim  192.168.0.11 2022-02-24 01:00:02
```

Alternative to extract the time:

```
df['time'].str.split().str[-1]
```

Full date operations alternative:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.to_datetime(df['time']).sub(pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01'))
```

Comment: Thanks.  `df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']+' ' +df['time'].str.extract('(\S+)$', expand=False) )` gives `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and 'str` Error.
Also, `df['time'].str` and `df['time'].str.split().str[-1]` gives error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`
I've pandas 1.3.3 version.  What could be the reason?